# How do I destroy a CakePHP session from inside of a test?

Tags: session, testing, cakephp, simpletest

I found a test that fails when run from a browser if you are logged in. I need to make sure the session is cleared out before running this test. Is there an easy way to clear the CakePHP session from within a test?

I tried calling Session::Destroy(); but the test cannot seem to get visibility of Session.

Maybe I am trying to import Session incorrectly? 
I am using: App::import('Core', 'Session');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe gustavotkg is correct. We should be using mock objects. Unfortunately, it will not be completely straight forward to do this the way the code was set up. I will have to go back and rework some things. For a temporary fix this is what I did:

```
$appController = ClassRegistry::init('AppController');
$appController->constructClasses();
$appController->Session->destroy();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should mock the Session component. Mark Story himself wrote an article showing [how to test controllers](http://mark-story.com/posts/view/testing-cakephp-controllers-mock-objects-edition).

Answer (score 0):

```
if(App::import('Core','Session')) {
  $session = new CakeSession();
  $session->start();
}
```

hope this can help you..